# Microsoft sql server managemenet studio is busy doing internal operations

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have SQL server 2016 standard edition SP1 and RAM,CPU all are normal when i got this message. Backups are fine running.

Database Size 2 TB and wants to expand the database from SSMS but it's taking long time to open and when i execute queries from Tables after DB expansion from SSMS is also taking long time to execute and finally got this 'Microsoft SQL server management studio is busy doing internal operations' message.

After 2 hours it came back normal but next day also it's bit slow while i uses GUI to see table or views.

Comment: Hi, do you start MS SQL Studio on a DB server or on a remote machine?

Comment: @vicky what is your  system configuration

Comment: @meow meow - On DB server

Comment: @A.Goutham - its  Processor Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2687W v4 @ 3.00GHz, 3000 Mhz, 8 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s),RAM146 Gigs,OS- windows 2016 datacenter edition,